# When can a function be written as superposition of Gaussians?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, signal-processing, wavelets

I read the following definition called Bump Algebra $B$:

> Let $g(t)=e^{-t^2}$ be a normal Gaussian function. $$B := \left\{ f \in C(\mathbb{R}) : f = \sum_i a_i \, g \left( \frac{t-t_i}{s_i} \right) \right\}$$where the sum is countable, and $a_i\in \mathbb{R}$, $t_i\in \mathbb{R}$, $s_i>0$ and  $\sum_i |a_i|<\infty$, and $C(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the set of continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$.

How could I determine whether a function $h\in C(\mathbb{R})$ belongs to the Bump Algebra $B$.

Comment: Do you want to $L^1$ (?) normalize your Gaussians?

Comment: Do you mean using the norm of $L^1(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: I see the Bump Algebra defined here is not contained in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ or $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, which is indeed a problem.

Comment: @Tibeku Yeah that was my issue. If you don't normalize your Gaussians, it's probably going to be tough to analyze this in general without bounding the $a_i$ (which is probably equivalent to just normalizing your Guassians anyway). You're also mixing norms here. $C(\mathbb{R})$ comes with the sup norm but your sum condition on the $a_i$ is more like an $L^1$ condition.